# replacing the content inside the tbody except one tr

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code in javascript where i need to replace the content inside the tbody except for the tr which has a class of template. I tried

```
$('#table').find('tbody').not(".template").html('<tr class="text-center"><td colspan="5">No Todo data</td></tr>');
```

but still it replace the whole tbody and not keeping the tr with a class of template.

this is the html

```
<table class="table" id="todo_list">
      <thead>
           <tr>
              <th scope="col">#</th>
              <th scope="col">ID</th>
              <th scope="col">Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Todo</th>
              <th scope="col" style="width:20%">Action</th>
           </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
            <tr class="template" hidden>
                <td class="cell"></td>
                <td class="cell"></td>
                <td class="cell"></td>
                <td class="cell"></td>
                <td class="cell text-center">
                   <button class="btn btn-warning btnUpdate" id="btnUpdate">Update</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btnDelete" id="btnDel">Delete</button>
                 </td>
            </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is very close; the main changes needed are:

- to select the tr elements of your tbody by adding `.find("tr")` (see below)
- use `.replaceWith()` rather than `.html()`

The revised approach can be understood as:

```
$('#table')       /* <- select element with id table and then */
.find('tbody')    /* <- select the tbody of that table and then */
.find('tr')       /* <- select the tr elements of that tbody and then */
.not('.template') /* <- filter tr elements that are not .template and then */
.replaceWith($('<tr class="text-center"><td colspan="5">No Todo data</td></tr>')); /* <- replace those resulting tr elements with new tr */
```

Here's an example of the updated code in action:

```js
$('#table')
.find('tbody')
.find('tr')
.not('.template')
.replaceWith($('<tr class="text-center"><td colspan="5">No Todo data</td></tr>'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Replace me</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="template" hidden>
      <td class="cell"></td>
      <td class="cell"></td>
      <td class="cell"></td>
      <td class="cell"></td>
      <td class="cell text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-warning btnUpdate" id="btnUpdate">Update</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btnDelete" id="btnDel">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Replace me</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As a final note, a more consise version that achieves the same result as shown above can be written as:

```
$('tbody tr:not(.template)', '#table')
.replaceWith($('<tr class="text-center"><td colspan="5">No Todo data</td></tr>'));
```

### Update

To replace all rows that do not have a class of `.template` with a single row that reads "No todo data" you can do the following:

```
var nonTemplateRows = $('tbody :not(.template)', '#table');
if(nonTemplateRows.length > 0) {
    nonTemplateRows
    .empty()
    .append($('<tr class="text-center"><td colspan="5">No Todo data</td></tr>'));
}
```

Comment: btw i have a thead and that changes it too

Comment: @Beginner thanks for that - just updated answer - does that help?

Comment: the result is weird. it creates 5 <tr class="text-center"><td colspan="5">No Todo data</td></tr> of this thats why i have a result of 5 rows with a display of no todo data

Comment: they dont have sir. thats the only row that has a class of template

Comment: yeah. but i dont understand why i have 5 tr's

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198478/discussion-between-dacre-denny-and-beginner).

Answer (score 1):

you could try this way ->
fetch html code of row with template class then append to it

```
$('#table').find('tbody').html(
'<tr>'+
$('#table').find('tbody').find(".template").html()+
'</tr>+
'<tr class="text-center"><td colspan="5">No Todo data</td></tr>');
```